# The argument type 'DateTime' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Timestamp'

Tags: flutter, datetime, google-cloud-firestore, datepicker, timestamp

I am using Firebase and Flutter and want to store a value of a due date, but I am getting conflicting messages which wont allow me to store it in the format I wish

model
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

```
class Task {
  final String id;
  final Timestamp due;


  Task({
    this.id,
    this.due,
  });

  factory Task.fromDoc(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return Task(
      id: doc.data()['id'],
      due: doc.data()['due'],
    );
  }
}
```

Writing Data

```
DateTime _date = DateTime.now();
  TextEditingController _dateController = TextEditingController();

void _selectDate() async {
    final DateTime newDate = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: _date,
      firstDate: DateTime.now(),
      lastDate: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 90)),
      helpText: 'Select date for task',
    );
    if (newDate != null) {
      setState(() {
        _date = newDate;
        _dateController.text =
            DateFormat("E, d MMM yyyy").format(_date).toString();
      });
    }
  }

TextFormField(
                                controller: _dateController,
                                onTap: _selectDate,
                                enabled: true,
                                readOnly: true,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Date'),
                              ),

Task task = Task(budget: _sliderValue, due: _date);
          DatabaseService.updateDate(taskId: _taskId, task: task);

  static void updateDate({String taskId, Task task}) {
    DocumentReference taskRef = tasksRef.doc(taskId);
    tasksRef.get().then((doc) {
      taskRef.update({
        'due': task.due,
        'budget': task.budget,
        'status': 'open',
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

try below code , I have use this code and its working for me

```
DateTime dateTime =  DateTime.tryParse(/*Your date */);
```

Comment: yeah that doesnt work now it thinks its a string. thanks for trying though

Answer (score 2):

The following line shows that `_date` is defined as `DateTime`:

```dart
DateTime _date = DateTime.now();
```

Here, you're trying to pass `_date` to `Task` constructor for `due` property:

```dart
Task task = Task(budget: _sliderValue, due: _date);
```

However, `due` property of `Task` must be a `Timestamp`:

```dart
class Task {
  final String id;
  final Timestamp due;

...
```

To fix the error, you need to convert `DateTime` to `Timestamp` using `Timestamp.fromDate()`.

```dart
Task task = Task(budget: _sliderValue, due: Timestamp.fromDate(_date));
```

Answer (score 0):

Firestore stores dates as `Timestamp`. The `Timestamp` class has a `toDate` method:

`final date = timestamp.toDate();`

Now you have the date as `DateTime`.

Comment: this works to render the date, but isnt helpful in this situation whereby its the date picker that needs to be DateTime